# function and class to show image not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, class, function

i am trying to get get the following working nothing is happen when i use the function i am trying to get it to display images

```
 class ItemRes {
//items DB
var $img="";


}
 function ShowItemImage($index,$res_a){
 if(sizeof($res_a) > $index){
 if($res_a[$index] != NULL) {
     $cimg = $res_a[$index]->img;
     return "<img src='$cimg' width='70' height='70' style='cursor:pointer'></img>";
 }
 }else{
     return "<center class='whitetxt'><strong>Empty</strong></center>";
 }
  }



 $res_array = array();
 $idx=0;
  $result21 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE eid='$eid' ORDER BY id DESC") or die (mysql_error()); 
  while ($row21 = mysql_fetch_array($result21)) { 
  $img_path = $row21['path'];
  $obj = new ItemRes();
  $obj->img = $img_path;
  $res_array[$idx] = $obj;
 $idx++;
 }

 ShowItemImage(0,$res_array)
 ShowItemImage(1,$res_array)
```

Comment: (suggestion) define "nothing is happen" in terms of material world, i.e. "blank screen", "no screen", "no computer" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thhere are many issues with this code, so I'll just take them one at the time.

Assuming you initiate the database connection somewhere else the first issue is 
the line:

`$result21 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE eid='$eid' ORDER BY id DESC") or die (mysql_error());`

Prior to this line you do not set the variable `$eid` and thus this will only fetch items with `eid = ''`
Second:

You do not end the last two rows with a semicolon, thus this will produce a fatal error.

Third:
Probably the reason to why you get *'nothing is happen'* (wich I interpet as a blank page)

In your function `ShowItemImage` you return strings but you do nothing with them.
You need to change this:

```
 ShowItemImage(0,$res_array)
 ShowItemImage(1,$res_array)
```

to:

```
echo ShowItemImage(0,$res_array);
echo ShowItemImage(1,$res_array);
```

and you will probably start noticing some things on the screen.